# Why does IE table-cell displays only when it has content?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, border

This is the HTML

```
<table class = "contact-table">
  <tr>
      <th>First Name(*):</th>
      <td>
          <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <th>Middle Name</th>
      <td>
          <asp:Label ID="lblMiddleName" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <th>Last Name(*):</th>
      <td>
         <asp:Label ID="lblLastName" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And this is the css

```
.contact-table th,
.contact-table td
{
   border: 1px Black solid;      
}
```

For **FF** and **Chrome**, things are working perfectly, i.e. **th** and **td** have 1px black border around. However, for IE, only td that have content have border.

Any reason for that?

## EDIT

When I add this **.contact-table td span**

```
.contact-table th,
.contact-table td,
.contact-table td span 
{
   border: 1px Black solid;      
}
```

The empty cells have border in IE, but then those cells that had border before, have an extra border inside the cells.

## EDIT

When I change the rules this way

```
.contact-table th,
.contact-table td span 
{
   border: 1px Black solid;      
}

.contact-table td span 
{
   width: 100%;      
}
```

It working perfectly for IE, but FF and Chrome now display small border that wrap only the text.

Is there a way to tell css to apply different rules depending on the browser?

Comment: Works fine here in IE9.

Comment: @j08691: I have IE9 as well. But it's displaying only td that have date on them, i.e. where the label has text to display. Middle-name label and other labels that are empty don't have borders.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6syzS/

Answer (score 1):

Do you have `empty-cells: show` set?

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ie/cc848860(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I have added empty-cells: show at the table level, but cells are still not displaying.

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach: Border-collapse is working, but for aesthetic reason, border-separate looks much better. If I can't make it work, I'll have to fall back to border-collapse.

Comment: @Richard77 Ok, back to the basics. What IE version exactly? (There are big differences!) Is your document in Standards Mode? Does it validate? Can you show an example page?

Comment: IE9. There's an icon that says compatible mode. However, click that icon is not making any difference.

Comment: @Richard77 Comparability Mode is usually a bad idea, since that requires you to work around the old IE6 misfeatures. Make sure that your document begins with a proper DOCTYPE (not a comment, not a `<?xml ... ?>` header). When in Standards mode and with `empty-cells: show`, IE should display the empty cells properly. BTW you didn't say if your document validates.